# How to find why my Java semaphore is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I wrote codes for traffic rules with thread and semaphore.

I think my codes are ok but it is not working. I mean it is not lock my second thread what I wrote under of my first thread. How can I find my error? why this not lock my second thread?

I want to see that result:
I'll have 6 car in the traffic. 3 car is on one way line (with different coordinate) and another 3 car is on another way line (with different coordinate). For example A coordinate is 5, B is 10 and C is 15.

Conversely, D is -6, E is -11 and F is -16. There are way crossing. if A,B and C car points are decreasing (every two second they coordinate decrease 1 by 1). They want to reach to "upTarget" for example 3. and D,E,F coordinate increasing one by one to reach -3. if A is reach to uptarget (to 3) before D reach his leftarget(to -3), all left line will wait until upline was leave 0,0 coordinate

I mean if A will reach to 3 then A B C line will be green light to go out and D,E,F will wait them until C coordinate will be 0

MainClass

```
package sample;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Main {
    public static int x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,upTarget,leftTarget;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Insert coordinant of A");
        x1=obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert coordinant of B");
        x2=obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert coordinant of C");
        x3=obj.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Insert coordinant of D");
        y1=obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert coordinant of E");
        y2=obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert coordinant of F");
        y3=obj.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Insert up target level");
        upTarget=obj.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Insert left target level");
        leftTarget=obj.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Traffic was start");
        Semaphore sem=new Semaphore(1);


        Thread t1=new MyBackend(sem,x1, x2, x3, upTarget, y1, y2, y3, leftTarget,"A");
        Thread t2=new MyBackend(sem,x1, x2, x3, upTarget, y1, y2, y3, leftTarget,"B");





        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }


}
```

My backend codes => my thread class

```
   import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class MyBackend extends Thread{
     Semaphore sem;
    private int x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,upTarget,leftTarget;
    private String value;

    public MyBackend(Semaphore sem,int x1,int x2,int x3,int upTarget,int y1,int y2,int y3,int leftTarget,String value){
        super(value);
        this.sem=sem;
        this.x1=x1;
        this.x2=x2;
        this.x3=x3;
        this.y1=y1;
        this.y2=y2;
        this.y3=y3;
        this.upTarget=upTarget;
        this.leftTarget=leftTarget;
        this.value=value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+sem.availablePermits());
        if(this.getName().equals("A")){
            try{

                while(x3>=0){
                    x1=x1-1;
                    x2=x2-1;
                    x3=x3-1;
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    System.out.println("A coordinate "+x1);
                    System.out.println("B coordinate "+x2);
                    System.out.println("C coordinate "+x3);

                    if(x1==upTarget){
                        sem.acquire();
                        System.out.println("yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+sem.availablePermits());
                        System.out.println("First line was reached!!!");
                    }
                }

            }catch(Exception e){}
            sem.release();
        }
        else {
            try{
                while(y3<=0){
                    y1=y1+1;
                    y2=y2+1;
                    y3=y3+1;
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    System.out.println("D coordinate "+y1);
                    System.out.println("E coordinate "+y2);
                    System.out.println("F coordinate "+y3);

                    if(y3==leftTarget){
                        sem.acquire();
                        System.out.println("Second line was reached!!!");
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){}
            sem.release();
        }    }
}
```

Comment: What are you observing, and what were you expecting exactly? Care to share any output!

Comment: I ll have 6 car in the traffic. 3 car is on one way line(with different coordinate) and another 3 car is on another way line (with different coordinate). For example A coordinate is 5, B is 10 and C is 15. Conversely, D is -6, E is -11 and F is -16. There are way crossing. if A,B and C car points are decreasing (every two second they coordinate decrease 1 by 1). They want to reach to "upTarget" for example 3. and D,E,F coordinat incresing one by one to reach -3. if A is reach to uptarget (to 3) before D reach his leftarget(to -3), all left line will wait until upline was leave 0,0 coordinate.

Comment: I mean if A will reach to 3 then A B C line will be green light to go out and D,E,F will wait them until C coordinate will be 0

Answer (score 0):

You code is working fine, the semaphore is working. Please change the while loop of thread B in your code to add more system.out.println() as below and see that while semaphore is acquired by thread A, Thread B is actually hanged (as expected).

```
                while(y3<=0){
                    y1=y1+1;
                    y2=y2+1;
                    y3=y3+1;
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    System.out.println("D coordinate "+y1);
                    System.out.println("E coordinate "+y2);
                    System.out.println("F coordinate "+y3);

                    if(y3==leftTarget){
                        System.out.println("Thread B acquiring sem: "+sem.availablePermits() + "If this is 0, D,E and F should hang");
                        sem.acquire();
                        System.out.println("Semaphore acquired, continue thread B for D, E and F"+sem.availablePermits());
                        System.out.println("Second line was reached!!!");
                    }
                }
```

If you were expecting something else, then please clarify.

### Update

Based on your comment, I think what you can do is add another if condition to check if semaphore has been acquired by the other thread or not, before changing coordinates as follows;

First set a static synchronised variable to show which thread acquired semaphore first.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

    public class MyBackend extends Thread{
         Semaphore sem;
        private volatile String acquiredBy = null;
        private int x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,upTarget,leftTarget;
        private String value;

        public MyBackend(Semaphore sem,int x1,int x2,int x3,int upTarget,int y1,int y2,int y3,int leftTarget,String value){
            super(value);
            this.sem=sem;
            this.x1=x1;
            this.x2=x2;
            this.x3=x3;
            this.y1=y1;
            this.y2=y2;
            this.y3=y3;
            this.upTarget=upTarget;
            this.leftTarget=leftTarget;
            this.value=value;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+sem.availablePermits());
            if(this.getName().equals("A")){
                try{

                    while(x3>=0){
                        if(acquiredBy != null && !acquiredBy.equals(this.getName())){
                              sem.acquire();
                        }
                        x1=x1-1;
                        x2=x2-1;
                        x3=x3-1;
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        System.out.println("A coordinate "+x1);
                        System.out.println("B coordinate "+x2);
                        System.out.println("C coordinate "+x3);

                        if(x1==upTarget){
                            sem.acquire();
                            acquiredBy = this.getName();

                             System.out.println("yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+sem.availablePermits());
                            System.out.println("First line was reached!!!");
                        }
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){}
                sem.release();
            }
            else {
                try{
                    while(y3<=0){
                        if(acquiredBy != null &&  !acquiredBy.equals(this.getName())){
                              sem.acquire();
                        }
                        y1=y1+1;
                        y2=y2+1;
                        y3=y3+1;
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        System.out.println("D coordinate "+y1);
                        System.out.println("E coordinate "+y2);
                        System.out.println("F coordinate "+y3);

                        if(y3==leftTarget){
                            sem.acquire();
                            acquiredBy = this.getName();
                            System.out.println("Second line was reached!!!");
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){}
                sem.release();
            }    }
    }
```

This should work!

Comment: It will not work! My want as result is that if x1=3 then lock second way's car (D,E,F) and continue the line 1 to his work.if last car (x3) in line 1 that equal to 0 then release lock of D E F car's and that car will be continue their way. Did you got my point? user give numbers to A B C D E F properly 5,10,15,-7,-12,-17. A,B,C car points going to reach to 3 (uptarget) and conversely E,D,F want to reach -3(lefttarget). The other way's car coordination will lock when which line's car will reach his target.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment. Please have a look

Comment: Some part of output       A coordinate 4
B coordinate 9
D coordinate -6
E coordinate -11
F coordinate -16
C coordinate 14
D coordinate -5
E coordinate -10
F coordinate -15
A coordinate 3
B coordinate 8
C coordinate 13
yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee0
First line was reached!!!
D coordinate -4
E coordinate -9
F coordinate -14
A coordinate 2
B coordinate 7
C coordinate 12
A coordinate 1
B coordinate 6
C coordinate 11

Comment: Add the Thread.sleep() to the first line of both while loops. It should be fine.

Comment: what's happening is thread a has acquired semaphore but at same time thread b has increased coordinates of d,e and f. You cannot stop thread b from working without calling sem.acquire, which we are doing before the coordinates are updated. You will ultimately need to rethink your approach to the problem in my honest opinion.